# Visual Basic - Change Mouse Speed on control only

Tags: vb.net, mouse

I need to change the mouse speed on a Picture Box in my VB paint program.

Is there a way to do this specifically for the object **without** changing the system's settings?

Comment: No, that's not possible.  Allow you user to zoom and pan the image instead.

Comment: You could try Reactive Extensions using and play around with tiners to see if you can get the desired result.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2012/06/14/testing-rx-queries-using-virtual-time-scheduling.aspx I would try asking someone on that team.  Here is a contact page that may help. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/contact.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than change the speed, you could modify the distance the pointer moves for each mouse event. This may not be a permanent solution, and if the UI thread is otherwise busy it could lead to jerky movement, but the technique is simply enough you could code it in less time than I took to write this paragraph.

1. In your event handler for MouseMove, get the distance (X,Y) the mouse pointer has moved.
2. Set Cursor.Position using some scaled value (nX, nY), where n determines the distance (and hence speed) the mouse pointer moves.

In other words, you'll be treating the mouse move increment as a vector, and you'll be multiplying that vector by a scalar value to modify the speed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx

As needed, use Boolean flags within the event handler to ensure that setting Cursor.Position does not trigger another even just because set Cursor.Position to a new point.

You might find that using the same scaling factor for all distances is inappropriate. For example, multiplying the move by a factor of 2 may be okay for short distances, but much too fast for large increments, in which case a lookup table or function would calculate the desired factor.

This technique would probably perform poorly if you need to decrease the speed of a move, as it could cause the mouse pointer to jump backward some fraction of the distance of its most recent move.